# How do I save my resized image to my Azure Blob Storage in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, imagesharp

I'm using the `ImageSharp` library to rescale my images before they are uploaded to Azure, the application hangs with no errors when it reaches the `UploadBlob` action and I think it's the stream causing it.  When the image is uploaded the information is gathered from the image stream, I create an empty `MemoryStream`, resize the image using `ImageSharp`, stuff the `MemoryStream` with my newly scaled image and try to upload that `MemoryStream` to Azure and I don't think it likes it as that is where it hangs.

Is MemoryStream the correct thing to use in this instance or is it something else?

**CarController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Car car)
{
    // Define the cancellation token.
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Access the car record
        _carService.InsertCar(car);

        //Get the newly created ID
        int id = car.Id;

        //Give it a name with some virtual directories within the container         
        string fileName = "car/" + id + "/car-image.jpg";
        string strContainerName = "uploads";

        //I create a memory stream ready for the rescaled image, not sure this is right.
        Stream outStream = new MemoryStream();

        //Access my storage account
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);

        //Open the image read stream
        var carImage = car.ImageFile.OpenReadStream();

        //Rescale the image, save as jpeg.
        using (Image image = Image.Load(carImage))
        {
            int width = 250;
            int height = 0;
            image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));                    
            image.SaveAsJpeg(outStream);
        }

        var blobs = containerClient.UploadBlob(fileName, outStream);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }            
    return View(car);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your code hanging? Why are you setting the image height to 0? Why are you doing `outStream.CopyTo(carImage)`?

Comment: If you look at my post you'll see that I state it hangs on the `UploadBlob` portion of my method.  The image height is set to `0` is specific to `ImageSharp` which will size the image to 250 and then calculate the height automatically o maintain the aspect ratio.  The stream copy was a test that didn't work and I've now removed.

Comment: No info when running under a debugger?

Comment: Not a thing, nothing in the browser console.  I even put in into a catch block and it still doesn't report anything back.  From the browsers perspective it posts and then waits.

Comment: @Yanayaya What is it `accesskey` you use to create `BlobServiceClient`? Is it account key? If so, please use connection string to create `BlobServiceClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not got anything to do with the ImageSharp library.

You need to reset your `outStream` position after saving. `BlobContainerClient` is trying to read from the end of the stream.